# Update my view depending on the status of my api call on a rails/react app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, gon

I have a rails app set up with react as front end. From my rails controller I am making a call to a browser based api. Through Watir and some "puts" inside my controller I can get the status of my call inside the terminal. For example in my terminal I will see "Loading 1%..." "Loading 10%" etc... until it is done.
What I am trying to do is to show this value to my front end app. Quite new to rails and not sure where to begin. In order to hit the call_api(username) method I am making a Ajax call from a button on my front-end. So far everything is working good. The only thing I would like to add is the status of my call on the client side.

I have tried using the gem gon but the problem is that my whole app is based on my root route "/" so if for example my index method is like this and my call_api method is like this

```
  def index
     @status = "started"
     gon.watch.status = @status
   end
```

```
  def call_api(username)
    @status = "new value for test"
    gon.watch.status = @status
    until @status == "Finished"
      @status = @browser.span(class: "monoFont").text
      puts "status" + @status
      sleep 1
    end
   end
```

When I go inside my browser console and I try to console.log(gon.status) I still get the value of "started" as my app is still on the index route. 
Probably there is a better way. Any help and recommendation on how to proceed is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I didn't get it exactly ! When your react component didmount your value is started and then after clicking a button and calling API you want to update the value? is this what you are going to do?

Comment: In order to use the API from my controller I need to scrape a website. While the API is running, using watir and scraping the website of the API,  I get some infos about the status (for example "Loading 10%", "Loading 20%" etc). This status info is displayed in my terminal using "puts". What I am trying to do is display it on my view. 
What makes it complicated is that I am using an ajax call to call the controller method ( def call_api(username)) so the only update I can get it's either what I puts inside my ajax success function or my ajax error function.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass a js variable to my window from my controller? knowing that the method scraping the api website is not my index method where my react front is displayed

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need a status updating continuously in your view while the API is doing some scraping on the web. So I think you may need web socketing or something like that?

Comment: Because your API is continuously running and you need a real-time update in your view. Take a look at web socketing and let me know the result.

Comment: Thank you Afsane. Looks like this is what I need to look into. Found this article that seems to fit my needs!
https://medium.com/@dakota.lillie/using-action-cable-with-react-c37df065f296

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong you need a status updating continuously in your view while the API is doing some scraping on the web. So I think you may need web socketing or something like that because your API is continuously running and you need a real-time update in your view. Take a look at web socketing.